# Using ILIKE on an ENUM in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

On a web frontend search, I would like users to be able to type 'wed', 'wednesday', 'Wed', etc. to select the day of the week. Given the enum set for days of the week, `('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')`, is it possible to use an ILIKE comparison on the values (`WHERE day ILIKE x`)? I haven't been able to make anything work and I haven't found anything through google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try casting to text:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where enum_column::text ILIKE 'Mon%';
```

Full example:

```
CREATE TYPE DAY AS ENUM ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');

CREATE TABLE test (t1 DAY);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Monday')

SELECT * FROM test where t1::text ILIKE 'Mon%';
```